# @Inject is injecting a new instance every time i use it

Tags: java, jsf, cdi

I have the following issue. 
(jboss 7.1 as, jsf 2 and myFaces extension filter)

Two managed beans. (I have cleaned up the code). I want to retrieve LoginBean from NextBean. The problem is that every time i inject the bean i get a new instance of LoginBean and not the current one. I have tried things like @Named("name"). The bean itself (both) are invoked from the jsf pages and all data is set, but a new instance is injected every time and i cant figure out what i'm doing wrong!!!

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class LoginBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8825740128333470396L;

    @EJB private UserDetailDao userDetailDao;

    private String description;
    public String getDscription() { return description; }

    public String submit() {
        userDetailDao.doSomething("test");

        description = "testing";

        return "next.xhtml";
    }
}
```

and the second bean

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class NextBean extends SomeBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4654827059950265300L;

    @Inject private LoginBean loginBean;

    public String submit() {
        String description = loginBean.getDscription();

        return "login.xhtml";
    }
}
```

The "Description" is set and i can see it in the jsf page, but i cant access it from NextBean since it injects a new instance every time! But the data is in the session!

:/

Any tips?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you _certain_ it is the same session?

Comment: A new one is not created. The two above are created, if i have a @PostConstruct then it is initialized once and the values that i insert in the above beans are included in the respective jsf views:/

Comment: Do you have the correct (CDI) SessionScoped class imported: `javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped` ?

Comment: @Matt: as per the comment on my deleted answer, yes.

Comment: @BaluC Thanks for your prior answer! I'm 100% sure I have the correct CDI classes imported! However i'm not sure the other beans have the correct ones! I will go home and if that's the case and if it is causing this issue! Other than that i have no clue :/ I'm trying to fix it the past two days!

Comment: @BaluC i haven't any jsf defined scopes or included packages :/ Strange! Banging my head against the wall!

Answer (score 0):

I was naming the beans wrong! and did not use proper @Produces :/

Thanks for your time lads.